# How to get Ignite Cache SQL Query to Return Value Object

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, caching, ignite

I have a Postgres database configured as my persistence layer and would like to execute SQL queries against the Postgres tables cached in Ignite.

Ideally, I'd like to execute a query on these caches and be returned the Value objects represented by these tables.

SqlQuery gives me the functionality that I am looking for but is deprecated.

`SqlFieldsQuery` would work, but I would prefer not to have to deal with the row data a List<?>.  Is there a way to get `SqlFieldsQuery` to return the value as an object and now as a list of its Fields?

I thought Continuous query could be a possible alternative but I am not interested in listening to cache updates and it is not compatible with `SqlFieldsQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_key` and `_val` keywords to retrieve the entire key and/or value objects.

```java
IgniteCache<Long, Person> cache = ignite.cache("Person");

SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(
        "select _val from Person where age > ?", 28);

try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql)) {
    for (List<?> row : cursor) {
        Person p = (Person) row.get(0);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Do you have links to documentation for these and other keywords?